# Deserialize json to list of object

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I got the following string (JSON) from WS:

```
{"cables":"[{\"rexelReference\":\"FIL01084259\",\"providerReference\":\"1084259\",\"productLibe\":\"CABLE BLEU D\\u0027INSTRUM 01IT09EGFA\",\"brand\":\"FIL\",\"color\":\"BLEU\",\"section\":\"0,9\",\"conductorNumber\":1,\"displayProduct\":true},{\"rexelReference\":\"FIL01084386\",\"providerReference\":\"1084386\",\"productLibe\":\"CABLE BLEU D\\u0027INSTRUM 01IT09EGSF\",\"brand\":\"FIL\",\"color\":\"BLEU\",\"section\":\"0,9\",\"conductorNumber\":1,\"displayProduct\":true}]","productNumber":"2"}
```

and these objects :

```
public class ProductList
{
   [JsonProperty("cables")]
   public List<ProductDTO> cables { get; set; }
   public int count { get; set; }
}

public class ProductDTO
{
    public string rexelReference;
    public string providerReference;
    public string productLibe;
    public string brand;
    public string color;
    public string section;
    public string conductorNumber;
    public string displayProduct;
}
```

When I try to deserialize with this code :

```
ProductList list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductList>(wsResponse2);
```

I get the error :

> *Additional information: Error converting value "[{" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[VoltaFront.DTO.ProductDTO]'. Path 'cables', line 1, position 14.*

I don't understand the problem. Is it because of the backslashes? Am I suppose to remove them before deserialization?

Edit now the error i get is :

> *Additional information: Error converting value "[{"rexelReference":"FIL01084259","providerReference":"1084259","productLibe":"CABLE BLEU D\u0027INSTRUM *<

Comment: check this site to validate your json http://jsonlint.com/ you will see that it's invalid

Comment: *Is it because of the backslashes?*, no. Those backslashes aren't really there. They are escape characters.

Comment: actually my copy/paste was wrong, i've edited my msg, the real json msg that i receive from WS is valid, but thx for your tool anyway

Comment: No, your JSON is still invalid. For some reason you have a `"` before the opening array bracket `[`. That probably shouldn't be there. How was your JSON produced in the first place? Because you probably need to tackle that problem first.

Answer (score 2):

You've a problem in the json format,
just remove the not used double quotes and use it like the following:

```
string wsResponse2 = "{\"cables\":[{\"rexelReference\":\"FIL01084259\",\"providerReference\":\"1084259\",\"productLibe\":\"CABLE BLEU D\\u0027INSTRUM 01IT09EGFA\",\"brand\":\"FIL\",\"color\":\"BLEU\",\"section\":\"0,9\",\"conductorNumber\":1,\"displayProduct\":true}]}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Json is not valid, after removing the escaping and put in JSON formatter and exception is thrown.

[Removing Escape](http://www.freeformatter.com/java-dotnet-escape.html#ad-output)

[JSON Formatter](http://www.freeformatter.com/json-formatter.html)

Fix your JSON. Here is the error msg:

```
Unable to format the JSON input. Expected a ',' or '}' at character 15 near 'les":"[{"rexelRefere'
```

Comment: yes my copy/paste was wrong, i've edited my msg, i've checked the real json msg that i receive from WS and it's valid

Comment: It is still not valid, check both link and you will see it.